# Tool to test a BigData Pipeline performance end to end?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana

I have this pipeline: Kafka->Logstash->ElasticSearch->Kibana

I have found a producer performance tool that can be invoked with the script “ bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh”.

I am wondering if anyone had any suggestions for testing performance end-to-end testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipeline `Kafka->Logstash->ElasticSearch->Kibana` involves 4 components. Kafka, Logstash, ElasticSearch, Kibana all of which serve a different purpose. Each component has different performance numbers and characteristics.

`bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` You mentioned is kafka performance test tool which will only measure performance of Kafka and not others. If you have configured pipeline to read, process and display data generated using above test tool then you can get overall pipeline performance. This way you won't be able to find out limiting component in pipeline.

I suggest you to configure a replicate a similar data which is required by your pipeline. Kafka custom producer - [PepperBox](http://pepperbox.gslab.com/) is good tool for that. Deploy monitoring on all components using influxDB/graphite (or any timeseries DB of your choice) and measure the end-to-end throughput as well as component wise throughput.

Sample benchmark is [YSB](https://github.com/yahoo/streaming-benchmarks). This will help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I want to mesure all pipeline performance from kafka to kibana such as latency and throughput